# Reduce the size of presented View controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use [voiceOverlay](https://github.com/algolia/voice-overlay-ios) github repo to integrate speech to text in my application.

I am initializing the voiceController as shown in the documentation.

```
self.voiceOverlayController.start(on: self, textHandler: { (text, final, extraInfo) in
            ...
```

The transitionView that is presented is currently occupying full screen. I want to provide a fix frame size to the controller so that some parts of the screen are accessible even if the viewController is presented. After looking at the pod files, here is where they are presenting the viewController. :

```
inputViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      view.present(inputViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

I understand that the `.overCurrentContext` is the full screen view controller and hence it is presenting it in the full screen view.

I am not able to identify if there is a way to resize the presentedViewController into a particular frame. Any leads would be appreciated.

Thank you

UPDATE: Based on Rob's advice in the comments, I tried changing from present to addChild approach. But I still couldn't get the desired results.

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to do.

Earlier code :

```
 inputViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      view.present(inputViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

New One :

where view is the parent UIViewController

```
view.addChild(inputViewController)
inputViewController.didMove(toParent: view)
setContraintsForPresenting(view: view)

fileprivate func setContraintsForPresenting(){
    InputViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
...
}
```

But when I try this, I get an error saying `Instance member 'view' cannot be used on type 'InputViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`

Comment: Look into using a container and presenting as a child view controller. I'm unfamiliar with the voiceOverlay library, but hopefully you can present the controller yourself. Pretty sure containment is what you are after.

Comment: Hey @Rob I tried the same but keep getting into errors, I have modified my question to define what I ve done. Can you take a look and let me know what is it that I am doing wrong here.